# can we use CSS file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

green fisher here again.
Here is my this time question:

can we use CSS file in javascript?

I indeed know how to do the that: **object.style = "";** 
however, if we can like do something really easy like: **import stylesheet.css**
then we can do something like **object.style = stylesheet.getStyleById('#something')**

well, those syntax above are all bullshit by my imagination, however, is there some similar way to do it?

Comment: Not even worth commenting on but here you go. Read the help docs and do your research before coming in here with such a lazy question.

Answer (score 1):

The more appropriate approach would be to add class names to your elements. Then use a regular CSS file to style per class name.

Include in a normal CSS file

```
.red-text {
   color: red;
}
```

Then add the relevant class name with JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("element").className += " red-text";
```

Comment: This overwrites possibly already added classes though.

Comment: @PeeHaa I updated to append the class name instead of override. OP will also likely need to be able to remove classes and avoid duplicate adding the class name - I'm just showing proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier way to do this is dynamically adding/removing classes/ids on the elements you want to style. You can do it using the jQuery [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) functions, or with the [element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) attribute.